# Axlsx Gem Moving Images within Merged Cells

Tags: ruby, axlsx

Im trying to setup a header on a spreadsheet that is created with the axlsx gem. In the header i want a logo and and image with text. When i set the start_at to [0,0] the image goes to the top left of the merged cells if i use [1,0] it goes to to far down. Is there a way i can adjust the image within the cells like a margin or padding?

## index.xlsx.axlsx

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Sites") do |sheet|

# Styles
styles = wb.styles
    header = styles.add_style(:bg_color => "282C87", :fg_color => 'FFFFFF')
    logo_image = styles.add_style alignment: {horizontal: :center}

img = File.expand_path(Rails.root+'public/images/mobile-logo.png')
name_img = File.expand_path('app/assets/images/name.png')
sheet.add_row [""],:height => 100
sheet.add_row ['SITE INFORMATION'], :height => 35
sheet.merge_cells("A1:L1")
sheet.merge_cells("A2:L2")

sheet.add_image(:image_src => img, :noSelect => true, :noMove => true, :style => logo_image) do |image|
      image.width=190
      image.height=90
end

sheet.add_image(:image_src => name_img, :noSelect => true, :noMove => true) do |image|
      image.width=600
      image.height=60
      image.start_at 2,0
end
 sheet.add_row ["ID", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Building Height", "Zoning Class", "State", "Town", "Zipcode", "County", "First Name", "Last Name", "Company Name"], :style => header
  @sites.each do |site|
    sheet.add_row [site.id, site.latitude, site.longitude, site.building_height, site.zoning_class, site.state, site.town, site.zipcode, site.county, site.first_name, site.last_name, site.company_name]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could add a row or column offset. Like this:

```
sheet.add_image(:image_src => img, :noSelect => true, :noMove => true, :style => logo_image) do |image|
    image.width=190
    image.height=90
    image.start_at 0, 0
    image.anchor.from.rowOff = 100000
    image.anchor.from.colOff = 100000
end
```

Comment: You made my day!